# How do I stop Windows from installing applications on update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

After installing the Windows Anniversary Update for Windows 10, I realized that there seems to be a feature that lets Microsoft install third-party applications from the Microsoft Store on my system, without my consent or knowledge (for example, *[Candy Crush Soda Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_Crush_Saga#Sequels)* or *[Farmville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FarmVille)*).

Anticipating that this might happen again in the future, is there a way to disable these kind of third-party application installations for future updates? Or will I always have to search and uninstall all these applications after each update?

Comment: Which edition of Windows 10 are you using? (Home, Pro, etc.)

Comment: I am using Windows Pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not happen again since Microsoft has stopped installing the previously uninstalled apps with each upgrade in the latest Windows Insider builds. So when you'll be upgrading to Windows 10 Creators Update which should come in March 2017, the apps such as Farmville will not be installed again.

Comment: Of course, MS could decide to add an application at any time along with updates...

Comment: Of course, but afaik uninstalled apps should remain uninstalled. And you'll be able to simply uninstall even more preinstalled apps such as Xbox and Mail, that you cannot uninstall right now..

Comment: BTW, after using DISM and SFC to fix issues, the process may reinstall previously removed items, such as Asian languages packs, and the same may happen with updates.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools such as [O&O ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) that separate some of the Windows 10 settings, providing control over discrete functions such as updating Windows OS and MS applications.

[image: ShutUp10 update controls]

Use any such application with caution... check the app at VirusTotal before use, and back up the OS drive, lest a change make the computer unusable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does this simply stop windows from updating (not what I want) or does it give me control over what is being inatalled with the update (what I want)?

Comment: It stops updates only, AFAIK.